# Filter Table results Self Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

Imagine a large table that contains receipt information. Since it holds so much data, you are required to return a subset of the data, excluding or consolidating rows where possible.

Here is the SQL and results table showing how the data should be returned.

```
create table table1
(RecieptNo smallint, Customer varchar(10),  ReceiptDate date,
 ItemDesc varchar(10), Amount smallint)


insert into table1 values
(100, 'Matt','2022-01-05','Ball', 10),
(101, 'Mark','2022-01-07','Hat', 20),
(101, 'Mark','2022-01-07','Jumper', -20),
(101, 'Mark','2022-01-14','Spoon', 30),
(102, 'Luke','2022-01-15','Fork', 15),
(102, 'Luke','2022-01-17','Spork', -10),
(103, 'John','2022-01-20','Orange', 13),
(103, 'John','2022-01-25','Pear', 12)
```

If there are rows on the same receipt where the negative and positive values cancel out, do not return either row.
If there is a receipt with a negative amount not exceeding positive amount, the negative amount should be deducted from positive line.

| RecieptNo | Customer | ReceiptDate | ItemDesc | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Matt | 2022-01-05 | Ball | 10 |
| 101 | Mark | 2022-01-14 | Spoon | 30 |
| 102 | Luke | 2022-01-15 | Fork | 5 |
| 103 | John | 2022-01-20 | Orange | 13 |
| 103 | John | 2022-01-25 | Pear | 12 |

This is proving tricky, any ideas?

Comment: What should be returned if the negative amount exceeds the positive amount? Both rows as they are?

Comment: This reads like homework. If others do your work for you, you won't learn anything. Please post what you have tried and some thoughts about why it isn't working. People around here will help but don't want to do it for you.

Comment: The negative amounts will never exceed the positive amounts just by nature of how the table is populated

Comment: @SeanLange This is not homework. I have just simplified the data so it is easier to follow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on table you provided, I suppose you want only row with the earliest date when you have multiple rows with same receipts which bring positive `Amount` after deduction.

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  *
,       SUM( amount) OVER (PARTITION BY RecieptNo ORDER BY RecieptNo, ReceiptDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS ActualAmount 
,       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RecieptNo ORDER BY RecieptNo, ReceiptDate) AS rn
FROM table1)
SELECT RecieptNo, Customer, ReceiptDate, ItemDesc, ActualAmount 
FROM cte 
WHERE ActualAmount > 0 AND rn = 1
```

Read about window functions and cte's though.